# Custom fields in WP and get_pages function

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have in my template-parts file where I created this code to list pages under page with ID=347 (I just wanted to create list of products using template file on one, single page). Code looks like this:

```
<?php $pages = get_pages(array('child_of' => 347, 'sort_column' => 'post_date', 'sort_order' => 'desc')); ?> 
<?php foreach ($pages as $page): ?>
<div class="fw-col-xs-12 fw-col-sm-4 product-box">

            <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($page->ID, 'large');?>
            <div class="fw-heading fw-heading-h3  naglowek-maly"><h3><?php echo $page->post_title; ?></h3></div>
            <a class="fw-btn fw-btn-1 button1" href="<?php echo get_permalink($page->ID); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr($page->post_title);?>"><span>check more</span></a>

</div><!--product box-->
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

And now I want to add extra field there using Advanced Custom Fields plugin. I need to display below the  small info (it will be product dimensions). So I created custom field and I am able to show field only if I add an ID of this page for example:

```
<?php the_field('product_dimensions', 200); ?>
```

How to make it dynamic? I was trying to use simply:

```
<?php the_field('product_dimensions'); ?>
```

But nothing shows then. Do I have to add there some extra code to read  the ID for each page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add $post->ID

```
the_field('product_dimensions', $post->ID);
```

Comment: Thanks! Works good for me but using $page->ID in my case. Thank You for showing me a good way :)